# How to use a greek symbol in grid.arrange()

Tags: r, ggplot2, x-axis

I am using the grid.arrange() function in R to parse together multiple plots. My current code is structured as follows:

```
grid.arrange(
plot1,
plot2,
legend,
ncol = 3,
top = "Change in Score",
left = "Change in Score"
)
```

I am trying to change the left = "Change in Score" to the Greek symbol "Delta" in order to replace "Change in."

No clue how to do this...Thanks for any suggestions!!

Comment: Use `left = expression(delta)` or `left = expression(Delta)`

Comment: @DohamedDesouky That is not working for me. When I use this code, the entire y-axis label disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the `iris` dataset as an example. You can use Unicode Characters for in this case Delta `\u0394`. You can use the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +geom_point()
plot2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +geom_point()

library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
grid.arrange(
  plot1,
  plot2,
  #legend,
  #ncol = 3,
  top = "Change in Score",
  left = "\u0394 Score"
)
```

Output:

[image]